# Want to disable album art in music player

Tags: music, music-player, album-art

My brain is wired to text. Album art conveys no useful information and I would like to just display the artist name and song title in large letters.

Is there a way to disable or drastically reduce the size of album art in *any* music player app? I've bought most of the popular ones and tried the stock player and many OEM players. They all want to display the album art and just put in a blank square if it's missing. Even apps with skinning functionality seem to always have the album art present.

Comment: Looks like the [Apollo player](https://github.com/ehcloninger/android_packages_apps_Apollo) is OSS. I've forked the build and I'll see about adding a "no album art" feature.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play Music has two modes, one of which displays the album art fairly small (about 1/8 of the display). It doesn't really use the space to give the title and the artist more prominence, though. On the other hand, instead of a blank square it uses auto-generated album art that consists of album and artist name and a solid coloured area.

Comment: I've seen that mode in Google Play, but I have to turn it on explicitly each time I start playing music. I'd like something that just dispenses with album art altogether.